# I can't get full text from tag parsing XML page

Tags: objective-c, xml

i have an xml tag <"text>", that have following text:

> Федя. Он хороший, добрый, энергичный пёс, которому отчаянно не хватает
>   удачи.Никто уже, никогда не узнает, что случилось с Федей.. "wall of
>   text".
> 8-910-444-59-42 Лариса

When i want to get that text out from that tag i only got last one, for that tag i got only "Лариса".

My question is how to fix it so i can see whole text? Maybe somehow that connected with "br" tag? All other tags extracted just fine, but not this..

```
#pragma mark - XML PARSER DELEGATE METHODS

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) isDescription = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"text"]) isText = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) isName = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"shortText"]) isShortText = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]) isImage = YES;

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"announcement"]){
        self.currentPosition = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

            self.imageUrlString = nil;
       }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"])
    {
        NSString *name = attributeDict[@"name"];

        if ([name isEqualToString:@"prev"]&& self.imageUrlString == nil)
        {
            NSString *urlString = attributeDict[@"url"];
            if (urlString)
            {
//                 NSLog(@"%@ found it", urlString);
                self.imageUrlString = urlString;
                [self.listOfImages addObject:self.imageUrlString];

            }
        }
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) isDescription = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"text"]) isText = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) isName = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"shortText"]) isShortText = NO;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]) isImage = NO;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"announcement"]){

        [self.listOfItems addObject:self.currentPosition];

    }

}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

    [self.delegate didFinishParsingToArray:self.listOfItems];
    [self.delegate didFinishParsingToImages:self.listOfImages];

//      NSLog(@"%@", self.currentPosition);
//    NSLog(@"%@ Its work", self.listOfImages);

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if (isDescription) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"description"];
    if (isText) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"text"];
    if (isName) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"name"];
    if (isShortText) [self.currentPosition setValue:string forKey:@"shortText"];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` implementation. In this method you need append together found strings for each parsed tag, but in your implementation you set each found string and in fact - last of found string (this method can be called more than once for a single tag).

Change your code with something like below:

```
if (isText) {
    if (currentPosition[@"text"])
    {
      NSMutableString *str = currentPosition[@"text"]
      [str appendString:string];
    }
    else
    {
      [self.currentPosition setValue:[NSMutableString stringWithString:string] forKey:@"text"]
    }
  };
```

Note: You can get a sample problem XML? I want to test my [XMLConverter](https://github.com/rsoldatenko/XMLConverter) on it.

Comment: How should i make complete string from those?

Comment: Thank you Ruslan, i appreciate your help very much) Спасибо ;)

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban всегда пожалуйса :), вообще при добавлении найденых строк нужно делать еще обрзеку незначащих символов наподобие незначащих пробелов и переводов строки. Но это по необходимости. И устанавливать значение не в `foundCharacters`,а в `didEndElement`, но это тоже дело вкуса. Если есть желание более глубоко разобраться с работой NSXMLParser - можно заглянуть в код [XMLConverter](https://github.com/rsoldatenko/XMLConverter) на Github. Там я постарался максимально пояснить работу кода комментариями.

Comment: Хорошо загляну обязательно ) Скажи пожалуйста а как заменить на пробелы <br />?

Comment: вот это как раз и делает обрезка с помощью 2x строк :`NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];` и `NSString *text = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: characterSet];`